# How to know the assembly code of a Windows system call using Visual Studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, x86, operating-system

I am interested in finding out the differences (implementation wise) between `timeGetTime()` and `GetTickCount()` Windows API functions, as the source code will not be public, I am thinking to analyse their implementation using their assembly code in Visual Studio, Can anyone suggest any better idea ?

Comment: Yes, single-step into it using a debugger on a test program that calls it.  You can easily see the user-space part of a function, but the kernel side (invoked by `syscall`) will be trickier.  Some API functions don't involve actual system calls, though.  Hopefully most time functions don't involve a user->kernel->user round trip; they don't on Linux.  (thanks to kernel data exported to user-space in the VDSO.  https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/)

Answer (score 2):

Use a debugger, like [Ollydbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/), [x64dbg](https://x64dbg.com/), [IDA pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) or Visual Studio itself for the user-mode code.
If you need to cross over to the kernel-mode side, use [WinDBG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools).

Make a program, as simpler as possible, that invokes the APIs you want to analyze then:

1. Load it in the debugger, if it is not a system-wide debugger.
2. Put a breakpoint on the APIs.
3. Run the program.
4. Once it breaks, single step as needed.

The more the debugger understand of Windows (read more debugging symbols it has) the easier the analysis.
WinDBG has a rich symbols library but it is a bit hardware to use.

---

To understand APIs like `GetTicksCount` you may find useful this pages:

- [What is the `KUSER_SHARED_DATA`](http://uninformed.org/index.cgi?v=2&a=2&p=15).
- [How to show the `KUSER_SHARED_DATA` memory region in WinDBG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-kuser).
- [Who updates the `KUSER_SHARED_DATA`](https://qmemcpy.io/post/who-updates-shareduserdata).
- [`KUSER_SHARED_DATA`](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/structs/kuser_shared_data.htm)

As [Peter Corders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51841380/how-to-know-the-assembly-code-of-a-windows-system-call-using-visual-studio#comment90635933_51841380) supposed, Windows exposes frequently accesses information, like the tick counts, in a memory region shared across all user-mode processes.
`GetTicksCount` only copy data from that (with some synchronization in place).

Comment: The best documentation I have seen on `KUSER_SHARED_DATA` is here:
https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/structs/kuser_shared_data.htm

Comment: Thanks @ForeverLearning!